# Error in configuring my old project

Tags: php, configuration, phpmyadmin, wamp

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg[Servers][$i][verbose] = localhost;
$cfg[Servers][$i][host] = localhost;
$cfg[Servers][$i][port] = "";
$cfg[Servers][$i][socket] = ‘/tmp/mysql.sock';  
$cfg[Servers][$i][connect_type] = socket;
$cfg[Servers][$i][extension] = mysqli;
$cfg[Servers][$i][auth_type] = config; 
$cfg[Servers][$i][user] = root;
$cfg[Servers][$i][password] = root;
$cfg[Servers][$i][AllowNoPassword] = true;

/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg[DefaultLang] = en-utf-8;
$cfg[ServerDefault] = 1; 
$cfg[UploadDir] = ;
$cfg[SaveDir] = ;

/* rajk - for blobstreaming */

$cfg[Servers][$i][bs_garbage_threshold] = 50;
$cfg[Servers][$i][bs_repository_threshold] = 32M;
$cfg[Servers][$i][bs_temp_blob_timeout] = 600;
$cfg[Servers][$i][bs_temp_log_threshold] = 32M;

?>


ERROR:- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in C:\wamp64\scripts\config.inc.php on line 11
```

I want to setup my project and getting this error can anyone please tell me the problem what i am doing in setup my old project into this. Tried many time in setting my project, getting same issue in this.

Comment: The code colouration should be a big clue here!

Answer (score 2):

Fancy quote on this line:

```
$cfg[Servers][$i][socket] = ‘/tmp/mysql.sock';  
                            ^ 
                          here
```

Change to this:

```
$cfg[Servers][$i][socket] = '/tmp/mysql.sock';
```

Also, you should be putting quotes around your indexes like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql.sock';
```

Comment: now getting this issue Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\wamp64\scripts\config.inc.php on line 23

Comment: Thats because of these lines `$cfg[UploadDir] = ; $cfg[SaveDir] = ;`, which you have set no value for. I suggest you take a look at some basic PHP syntax guides, these are very simple issues.

Comment: can u please tell me if your answer is helpful

Comment: Don't know what you mean, thats for you to decide. You need to set those variables to something, even if its just an empty array `[]` or string `''`.

Comment: Plus all the unquoted values like `socket` and `mysqli` etc etc